# automatic photo capturing in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

SO far I have android code running on the client side. User can click the button to start the camera. Camera starts working. User has to click the button to take the pictures and then click "DONE" button. The image is then saved and I send it to the server later on.

I am now looking to automate this process i.e. when user starts the camera, picture should be taken automatically and then controls returns to the parent screen. I was wondering if this is possible then how???

Will be waiting for your guidance. My camera code is as follows:-

protected void startCameraActivity() {

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(new File(file_name)));
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: can u state some example plz . . . it will be really helpful

Comment: This [Tutorial](http://androiddevblog.blogspot.com/2010/07/controlling-android-camera.html) should help IMHO.

Comment: is there any way i can do the same with MediaStore with some change in settings perhaps . . ?

Comment: @user1388142 can you paste the code of your camera activity please. In my app i need the same functionality, but what i am doing is click a button ---> opens camera ---> capture a picture ---> automatically saves to the gallery and gallery is opened ----> select the captured image ----> click button to upload to a server.....i want to avoid opening gallery and selecting, i just want a preview of the captured image in my imageview as soon as i capture a image and then on clock upload...or else give a link which u followed

Comment: hi my code saves the image on android phone. Plz tell me ur email I will send u the whole project ! !